# How can I get a List of elements to click through the array - only does it once

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

// This code will get the first 5 elements and display the correct text

```
List <WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/section/div/article/div/div[1]/ul/li")); 

    int size = 0;
    if (allElements.size() < 4) {
        size = allElements.size();
    }
    else {
        size = 4;
    }

        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) 
          System.out.println(allElements.get(i).getText());
}
```

I changed the getText() to click() but it only gets one more in the array and then terminates.   Why??

```
List <WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/section/div/article/div/div[1]/ul/li")); 

    int size = 0;
    if (allElements.size() < 4) {
        size = allElements.size();
    }
    else {
        size = 4;
    }

        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) 
                allElements.get(i).click();
}
```

Should say that this to test pagination but I do not want to go more than 4 pages as some of the areas where this would be tested could have a large number of pages.

Comment: You have to save each link as a string and pass it in another loop. Whatever you have done works only for first link because the second link may need to be clicked from the homepage.

Comment: How do I save the link??   The text is just the page number not the actual link ir is that ok.   Thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If so can you share it? It could be a case that the second element in your array is not clickable straight after clicking the first?

Comment: Initialise in this way `String ar[]=new String[4];`  and navigate to each link `for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) 
         {
           driver.navigate().to(ar[i]);
         }`

Comment: Actually I got it working by using the javascript executor.  Had not worked with arrays for awhile so looked it up before these answers.   Here is the code that works:

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got it working by using the javascript executor.  Here is the code:

```
// Test pagination
        List <WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/section/div/article/div/div[1]/ul/li")); 

        int size = 0;
        if (allElements.size() < 4) {
            size = allElements.size();
        }
        else {
            size = 4;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            pageLinks[i] = "/html/body/div[1]/section/div/article/div/div/ul/li[" + allElements.get(i).getText() + 
                "]/a";
            System.out.println(pageLinks [i]);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            WebElement pageLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(pageLinks [i]));
            System.out.println(pageLink);
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", pageLink);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
```